# How to setup paid account features in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a free and paid account setup on my android app.
Free data is stored in room db. 
And when paid user is logged in I need to deliver paid data to app and user can access paid data in offline. Both paid and free data is synced from firestore. 
How to setup these things in android?
Please help and sorry for my English.

Comment: Categorise your data with isPaid = 0 or 1 then apply query in firebase isuser paid or not

Comment: What should do when user is logged out?

Comment: Hi @nabeel, welcome to SO. Your question is getting downvoted (and might be closed) because it does not meet community guidelines - it basically asks for a tutorial, not for help with a specific problem. Please read [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better results when using the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios in your question.

1. While releasing the app, you can release as free app or paid app. 
   If this is the case, you need to release 2 different apps (one as paid and the other as free).You need to display different content for each app.
2. Purchase is happening in the app (i.e InApp Purchase)
   If this is the case, you need to maintain payment logs against each user while the payment is made. Validate the same when the user logs in.

Note: You can maintain the payment data in sqllite,external server based on your requirement.

Comment: Do I need to delete offline paid data from app when user logs out?

Comment: yes clear data during logout and while login get payment details(paid/unpaid) from server for that particular user and process it..